# SQL Server - Change clustered index without dropping primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, clustered-index

I want to change the clustered index on a table to a column combo other than the primary key.

How can I drop the clustered index, keep the same primary key I have, and add a new clustered index on a new set of columns.

Final result - Non-clustered indexed PK, clustered index on new set of columns.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this is:

1) First Drop the constraints with the below code:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME DROP CONSTRAINT ConstrainName
```

2) Then Create the Clustered Index on the Column you want with the below code:

```
Create clustered index Index_Name on TableName (column1,column2)
```

3) Create a primary key on a column :

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (ColumnName);
```

Comment: (I'm assuming your "First drop the constraints" is about the foreign key references.) Note that tables can only have one clustered index. You'd have to drop the original clustered index before creating another.

Comment: In step one...is that constraint the PK? So I'm dropping the PK? Because in step three you then set the PK.

Comment: Yes in step 1 we need to drop the PK and in step 3 we are re-creating it